# How to select the data where value in column A is the same, while certain value does not exist in column B?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database. In Column A, I have the names of the work orders. In Column B, I have the current/past status of the work order. I would like to Select only those work orders from Column A, where certain status of the work order is not present.

This is the query that I am trying:

```
SELECT work_order FROM table WHERE status IN ('B10') AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT work_order FROM _2221_002 WHERE status IN ('V40'))

work_order | status
123456     | B10
123456     | B40
123456     | V40
234567     | B10
234567     | B40
345678     | B10
345678     | B40
345678     | V40
```

I am getting empty selection. However, I would like to see the work_order output of 234567, because that is the only work_order that is missing the 'V40' status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
SELECT work_order FROM table WHERE status='B10'
MINUS 
SELECT work_order FROM table WHERE status = 'V40'
```

The minus operator is explicitly defined exactly for cases like this where you want to have elements that are part of one set, but not of another set of data from your table.
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php
http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-minus/

As mentioned by OP, Postgre calls this operator EXCEPT.

Comment: Thank you, working with EXCEPT (PostgreSQL alternative of MINUS)

Answer (score 0):

One simple option uses aggregation:

```
SELECT work_order
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY work_order
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'V40' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

If you are using Postgres 9.4 or later, we can shorten the `HAVING` clause using `FILTER`:

```
SELECT work_order
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY work_order
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE status = 'V40') = 0;
```